# How can I create an OmniSearch using OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to create a "search-for-anything" using the OSM data. I know the `name` column is the most relevant attribute, but it come empty sometimes.

What tags I must include in my query to return the maximum data possible of a search?

Example: When the user search for `Peter` I need to return roads, places, hospitals, etc... with this parameter in the name.

I'm using Java to query the `planet_osm_*` tables in a PostGIS database. I'm planning to create an Ajax autocomplete method in the HTML users interface to query the database for any word the user types.

Comment: How are you searching the name column now? What program/language/method are you using?

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Editing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things just don't have a name. For example some minor parks, many forests, parking areas, fountains, post boxes, elevators, waste baskets and so on. Do you want to search for all these things? Then the only option for you is to look at all the corresponding [tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). See [Map Features](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) for the most important ones. The keys [operator](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:operator) and [brand](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:brand) are also very important depending on your use-cases.

Comment: I'll be happy searching just what is possible. I just need to know if I can use only the `name` column or we have some important other. Of corse we have the tag values, but will be impossible to search everyone. The common ones will be enough.

Comment: As already explained in my answer not every object has a name. If you want to search for objects that don't have a name then you will need to look at other tags, too. See [taginfo](https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/keys) for the most popular keys. Currently *name* is only on rank 6.